# NuxtJS page URL with anchor links not working on desktop Safari and iOS

Tags: vue.js, url, safari, nuxt.js, anchor

I find it baffling, but opening a URL with anchor link does not work in Safari and iOS (mobile Safari). So imagine I have a mobile app with a link to a specific section in T&Cs on my website and it does not scroll to that section. When I try to copy and paste a URL into the new browser window, same result - stays on top of the page. The only time it works, is when I have table of contents, page loads and I click on the anchor link manually.

I have read many answers here and I can confirm that:

- the anchored element with id="my-anchor" is definitely present in the source of the page
- I have a trailing slash at the end of the URL, before the anchor
- when I open http://www.example.com/my-page/#my-anchor I do not get any redirect, I can see it is 200 response ( so argument about Safari loosing anchor on redirect does not work )
- the anchored element we are trying to link to is  heading

Chrome, Firefox and even Edge work like a charm. Please help me because marketing team thinks I am incompetent.

The culprit is Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4).

The page is generated using Nuxt framework (VueJS).

Comment: I have the very same problem. No documentation on this and can't work out whether this is Nuxt specific issue or the original Safari bug

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I'm not entirely sure why.

```
<nuxt-link 
    :to="{ path: link.url, hash: (link.anchor ? '#' + link.anchor : '')}">
    {{ link.label }}
</nuxt-link>
```

I happen to be passing in the nav items so have a mix of anchors and normal links, but I equally could have used the following for one-off links. Again, I'm not sure why splitting it out like this fixed the iOS Safari bug but it did for me

```
<nuxt-link to="{ path: '/', hash: '#contact-form'}">
    Contact
</nuxt-link>
```